# nginx-ingress add custom header for a specific path

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I have the following nginx-ingress in a kubernetes environment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "cache-control: no-store";
      more_set_headers "MyCustomHeader: Value";
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: svc1
          servicePort: 80
          # Want to add the custom headers in this path only
        path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: svc2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /cacheable-path
```

I have a couple of headers that I want to set `Cache-Control` and `MyCustomHeader`. But I want these headers to be set only for the root path `/` and not for other routes (like `/cacheable-path`).

How to achieve this ? Adding the annotation causes the header to be appended to all the responses. I want the headers to be added to a specific path only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to add headers for a specific path in a single Ingress resource. You will have to create two Ingress resources.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "cache-control: no-store";
      more_set_headers "MyCustomHeader: Value";
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: svc1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

**Without header**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: svc2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /cacheable-path
```